# bash- use filename to append to every line in each file using sed

Tags: bash, sed, find

I have multiple files named as such --> 100.txt, 101.txt, 102.txt, etc.

The files are located within a directory. For every one of these files, I need to append the number before the extension in the file name to every line in the file.

So if the file content of 100.txt is:

```
blahblahblah
blahblahblah
...
```

I need the output to be:

```
blahblahblah 100 
blahblahblah 100
...
```

I need to do this using `sed`.

My current code looks like this, but it is ugly and not very concise:

```
dir=$1
for file in $dir/*
do
    base=$(basename $file)
    filename="${base%.*}" 
    sed "s/$/ $filename/" $file
done
```

Is it possible to do this in such a way?

```
find $dir/* -exec sed ... {} \;
```

Comment: "and preferably with `find` alongside" Is there any particular reason why you *want* to use `find`?

Comment: I edited. Doesn't have to be with find, if there is a more concise way, but I do need sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you already have is essentially the simplest, shortest way of performing the task in bash. The only changes I would make are to pass `-i` to `sed`, assuming you are using GNU sed (otherwise you will need to redirect the output to a temporary file, remove the old file, and move the new file into its place), and to provide a default value in case `$1` is empty.

```
dir="${1:-.}"
```

Comment: Add `cd $dir` before the loop and the basename calls be dropped with a simpler `*` glob.

Answer (score 0):

the following command line will find all files that that has filename with **only numbers with an extension** and append the filename (numbers) at the end of each line in that file..**(I tested with a couple of files**)

```
find <directory path> -type f -name '[0-9]*' -exec bash -c 'num=`basename "{}"|sed "s/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\..*/\1/"`;sed -i.bak "s/.$/& $num/" "{}"' \;
```

Note: command line using sed not tested in OS X

replace  `<directory path>` with the path of your directory

Comment: not sure why the down vote, this worked fine, however one issue on OS X, it creates files called file.txt.bak for every file in the directory.

Comment: Yes..If you don't want to backup file instead of "sed -i.bak" in the command line, use "sed -i"...